# Rails is not inserting recoreds into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I am new to Rails, and I'm having trouble with inserting new records into the database using my Car model.

The application is as follow:
I have build the articles basic tutorial application as defined in the Rails official website, until section 5.9

I added user authentication useing devise, and I wanted to add a model -cars - that has assosiation with the user. user has_many cars, and a car belongs_to a user.
This is the user.rb model file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
 has_many :cars
end
```

The cars.rb file is:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
end
```

The cars table is structed like so:

```
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :img

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I added user assosiation with:

```
class AddUserIdToCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :cars, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Now, when I use rails console I see that the cars table and user table are created, and creating users works fine.

Alse, when I try to create a new car, I'm redirected back to my car list, and nothing is loaded, and when I check the console I see that the cars table is empty.

the cars controller is:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @cars = Car.all
    end
    def new
    end
    def show
        @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    end
    def create
        # render plain: params[:car].inspect
        @car = Car.new(car_params)
        @car.save
        redirect_to @car
    end
    private
    def car_params
        params.require(:car).permit(:title, :description, :img)
    end
end
```

the cars/new view is:

```
<h1>Add new car</h1>

<%= form_with scope: :car,
url: cars_path,
local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :description %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :description %>
  </p>

    <p>
    <%= form.label :img %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :img %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', cars_path %>
```

and the cars index view is:

```
<h1>Listing cars</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th>Img</th>
  </tr>

  <% @cars.each do |car| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= car.title %></td>
      <td><%= car.description %></td>
      <td><%= car.img %></td>

      <td>
      <%= link_to 'Show', car_path(car) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'New Car', new_car_path %>
```

when I post a new car or go to index page, there is no error, and the very same structure in the article section (that I created with the rails official tutorial) works fine.

When I navigate to path/cars or when I submit a new car I see an empty table.
When I try to use show, by navigating to cars/:id, there is an error that no car with this id exist - another testemony that no records are inserted.

I'm very new to Rails, so I'm sorry if there is not enough info/I shared to much info. If more info is needed please tell me.

I have seen most questions with similar topics, and didn't find any relavent answer there. I saw this, among others:

[Insert into Rails Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332408/insert-into-rails-database)

[Rails 4 not inserting values into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121885/rails-4-not-inserting-values-into-database)

[Ruby on Rails not adding record to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525139/ruby-on-rails-not-adding-record-to-database)

[Rails 5: ActiveRecord not creating record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167081/rails-5-activerecord-not-creating-record)

This is the rails log for create cars

```
Started POST "/cars" for ::1 at 2019-10-20 16:46:15 +0300 Processing by CarsController#create as HTML Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"MZYIt+YOELCPSFbZZmammwr7LrdMWQfzlge3k/h8UftwBjqgzHHH9VqHBFHAiwXi2Ej2Y4jM2xhC/V7sil773Q==", "car"=>{"title"=>"car3", "description"=>"123123", "img"=>"123"}, "commit"=>"Save Car"} Redirected to localhost:3000/cars Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1322
```

Why no car is being inserted while an article does, even tough the functions and erb files are practicaly the same?

Comment: Show us your rails logs while inserting a new car. The logs can be found at `log/development.log`.

Comment: @sureshprasanna70
is this the relevant part?

Started POST "/cars" for ::1 at 2019-10-20 16:46:15 +0300
Processing by CarsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"MZYIt+YOELCPSFbZZmammwr7LrdMWQfzlge3k/h8UftwBjqgzHHH9VqHBFHAiwXi2Ej2Y4jM2xhC/V7sil773Q==", "car"=>{"title"=>"car3", "description"=>"123123", "img"=>"123"}, "commit"=>"Save Car"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/cars
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're on rails 6. So, by default, when a `Car belongs_to :user`, then `user_id` on `@car` is required. But, in your `create` action, you're never setting `user_id` on `@car`, so `@car` is not saving.

If you think a save is supposed to be working and it's not, you can always do `save!` instead of `save`. The banged version of the method will raise an error if the save is unsuccessful.

Anyway, I think the `create` action in your `CarsController` ought to look something more like:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @cars = Car.all
  end

  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  def show
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @car = current_user.cars.new(car_params)
    if @car.save
      redirect_to @car
    else
      # do something else
    end
  end

  private

  def car_params
    params.require(:car).permit(:title, :description, :img)
  end

end
```

By doing `current_user.cars.new`, `user_id` is automatically set on the new `Car` and you should be able to save.

In response to your questions in comments:

> Why current_user.cars.new(car_params) and not: current_user.Car.new(car_params)? Why no capital Car was needed, like in Car.find?

`Car` is a class. `Car.new` calls the `new` method on the `Car` class. `Car.find` calls the `find` method on the `Car` class. `Car` is *not* a method on `current_user`. Therefore, `current_user.Car` makes no sense and should throw an error.

`cars` (when used like `current_user.cars`) is a method on the `current_user` instance of `User`. The `.cars` method is created when you do `User has_many :cars`. You can see a listing of all the methods created by `has_many` in the [Methods Added by has_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many) section of the [Active Record Associations](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide.

`current_user.cars` returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation`. When you do `current_user.cars.new`, you're calling the `new` method on the `ActiveRecord_Relation` returned by `current_user.cars`. This `new` method returns an instance of `Car` that *already has user_id set*, which is the point of the whole thing. So:

1. `Car.new` returns a new `Car` **without** `user_id` set,
2. `current_user.cars.new` returns a new `Car` **with** `user_id` set.

> why cars? as I understand, cars is a refrens to the table, and not the car model itself.

No. As stated above, and in this context, `cars` is a method on `current_user` that is created when you do `User has_many :cars` and that returns a `ActiveRecord_Relation` representing all of the `Car` instances that have a `user_id` that matches `current_user.id`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!
Just two last questions:
1) Why current_user.cars.new(car_params) and not: current_user.Car.new(car_params)? Why no capital Car was needed, like in Car.find?
2) why cars? as I understand, cars is a refrens to the table, and not the car model itself.

Comment: See updated answer with responses to your questions.

Comment: Thanks again. You are a life saver